# What’s the part reference for the knocking sensor’s plug of my car?

Tags: toyota, yaris, vin, lpg, knock-sensor

I just changed the engine of my car, but a part from the new engine is missing as the old engine knocking sensor doesn’t fit inside the engine (despite both new and old engine being 190000J060 compatible).

I know that plug/contact isn’t sold separately from wires to the ECU but even for the complete part I don‘t have the reference so I can’t search it online.

So how to find what I need to buy from the VIN code of the old engine which is `VNKKL96380A230263` as local Toyota is refusing to sell that part to me (or even tell the reference number so I can find it in a car scrappage)?

Comment: Probably the best place to find that plug is a scrap yard... Pity you did not get it when you got the replacement engine... One of the things I tend to do... You will probably find that it is not a part sold individually and it comes with the complete engine loom...

Comment: @SolarMike yes but which scrap yard? I contacted the http://nbd.se and they told me they burnt the wires with the spark plug of the engine I bought but they. http://ndb.se did so because they thought there would be no compatibility problem (they even asked my VIN) but they were wrong. Toyota told me they could install the plug for 700€ (yes just for the contact and the wires to the ECU since the plug can’t be sold separately whereas http://nbd.se was Ok for selling the whole part below 20€). **My best luck is to Google for the whole part which include the wires but I’ll need the reference**.

Comment: I can suggest my favorite scrap yard (Sndwich, Kent) but that is probably totally useless for you... Find a scrap yard where you can go around the vehicles and take the parts off yourself... And the scrap yards I go to don't tend to use part numbers...

Comment: @SolarMike short Story. In the home country of Peugeot and Citroën and Reanault most cars are from those brands. Toyota cars are rarer, so not only I didn’t found what I need but I was unable to find a scrap yard with a Toyota Yaris at 30Km acound (compatible or not). **Lifting the damaged car is also required** to look if the it’s the right part. So my best luck is to Google the reference and import a used part from a foreign country like I did for the engine.

Comment: A good answer needs a good question - leaving out pertinent information does not help anyone...

Comment: @SolarMike **At that point I’m seriously thinking about a way to weld the wire directly to the knock sensor which could be a written answer to this question**. I also have my left feet broken so I have many unpaid bills telling things like «please go to our office with your debit card to fix this issue» nor I’m able to go to the doctor because I’m unable to wear shoes.

Comment: Any plug with the correct number of terminals will work if you are prepared to swap them ...

Comment: @SolarMike no the old one is larger than the required part so it don’t fit in the new engine.

Comment: I meant source a plug and socket ... but just joining the (correct) wires may be a quicker solution unless you want to keep the car "concours"...

Comment: @SolarMike the problem is [the shape of the sensor](https://spareto.co.uk/system/products/1172348/original/45943-knock-sensor.jpg?1540589463)

Comment: @SolarMike I’m neverless interested in knowing if your scrap yard has a Toyota Yaris I’m looking for. What’s their email address?

Comment: google scrap yards, Sandwich, Kent...

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the link you give in the comments, I would get two electrical connectors that go on to those pins and solder them on to the wires.

Then I would spray a small amount of silicone lube into the socket, fit the wires and then fill / pack with an insulating compound that goes hard - making a male connector like that...

Comment: The problem is getting silicon that can resist the heat.

Comment: I suggested silicone as the lube to stop sticking...

Comment: Etencheity is required. Need to find something else.